# Log Canonical Threshold Equals 1

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

I'm an analyst interested in what we would call the "critical integrability index" which, for a given (real-valued) function $f$ is the supremum of $\sigma$ such that $|f|^{-\sigma}$ is integrable on a neighborhood of the origin. I've recently learned that this is essentially the same as the "log canonical threshold" in algebraic geometry. My question is:

Is it known that the polynomials with lct=1 form an open subset of the space of all homogeneous polynomials of degree $k$ in $n$ variables? Are they known to be generic?

I prefer real answers but would still find complex answers enlightening. I'm aware that in general the lct is not semicontinuous, but I wonder if lct=1 is better-behaved than the general case. I've also seen some results about lcts of hypersurfaces being one, but I haven't yet decoded how these relate to my version of the question.

Comment: Just to check, since your question appears to span both algebraic geometry and real analysis: what topology do you impose on the space of degree $k$ homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I prefer the standard topology (Euclidean balls and all that) but Zariski would be great, too. Also since it's real, lct$\geq 1$ is also just as good for me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: what is an "Euclidean ball" around a homogeneous polynomial? Do you wish to treat the coefficients as living in a topological vector space whose basis elements correspond to degree k monomials?

Comment: I am familiar with the complex case. It is easy to see that we can decompose $\mathbb P ^N=|\mathcal O (k)|$ in to locally closed subsets corresponding to a fixed lct (see http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9601026.pdf eg 7.6 and 8.6). The general polynomial defines a smooth hypersurface and so has lct=1 (if you want lct = 1 at the origin, you need to consider homogeneous polynomials vanishing there).

Comment: BTW do you have a survey style reference for real lct's (as opposed to over $\C$)?